# PyQt4 - clicked.connect is remembering previous connection?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

So basically I have a main menu with multiple button on, when one is clicked it should change layouts to the new window. This works fine, but when I click using the return button on the new window, when I click another button on the main menu it takes me back to the first clicked one.

I am a complete noob at this, the code is so rough its just a practice, but I cant figure it out!!!

(try not to laugh at the code/variables its just a test app

I have programmed 2 keys to work:

```
 def Layout(self):

    verticle = QVBoxLayout()
    Horizontal = QHBoxLayout()
    Horizontal_pic = QHBoxLayout()


    self.btn_feed = QPushButton("Feed")
    self.btn_status = QPushButton("Status")
    self.btn_play = QPushButton("Play")
    self.btn_fight = QPushButton("Fight")


    Horizontal.addWidget(self.btn_feed)
    Horizontal.addWidget(self.btn_status)
    Horizontal.addWidget(self.btn_play)
    Horizontal.addWidget(self.btn_fight)


    self.pic = QLabel()
    self.pixmap = QPixmap("{0:^10}".format("charmander.png"))
    pixmap = self.pixmap.scaledToHeight(344)
    self.pic.setPixmap(pixmap)
    self.btn = QLabel(" ")

    Horizontal_pic.addWidget(self.btn)
    Horizontal_pic.addWidget(self.pic)
    Horizontal_pic.addWidget(self.btn)

    verticle.addLayout(Horizontal_pic)
    verticle.addLayout(Horizontal)

    self.mainwindow = QWidget()

    self.mainwindow.setLayout(verticle)

    self.setGeometry(700, 300, 500, 500)

    self.btn_status.clicked.connect(self.statusbutton) #button 1 
    self.btn_feed.clicked.connect(self.feedbutton) # button 2

    def statusbutton(self):
    self.Status()
    self.stacked.addWidget(self.statuslayout)
    self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(1)
```

Here are the methods to call the layouts

```
def statusbutton(self):
    self.Status()
    self.stacked.addWidget(self.statuslayout)
    self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(1)

def feedbutton(self):
    self.Feed()
    self.stacked.addWidget(self.feedlayout)
    self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(1)

def mainlayout(self):
    self.Layout()
    self.stacked.addWidget(self.mainwindow)
    self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(0)
```

here are the layout/windows it changes to

```
    def Status(self):
    font = QFont("Comic Sans MS",15)

    Overall = QHBoxLayout()

    horz1 = QHBoxLayout()
    horz2 = QHBoxLayout()
    horz3 = QHBoxLayout()

    self.pic = QLabel()
    pixmap = self.pixmap.scaledToWidth(250)
    self.pic.setPixmap(pixmap)

    verticlepic = QVBoxLayout()
    verticlepic.addWidget(self.pic)

    lbl_hunger = QLabel("Hunger ")
    lbl_hunger.setFont(font)
    lbl_age = QLabel("Age      ")
    lbl_age.setFont(font)
    lbl_attack = QLabel("Attack  ")
    lbl_attack.setFont(font)




    horz1.addWidget(lbl_hunger)
    horz1.addWidget(QLineEdit(str(self.hunger)))
    horz2.addWidget(lbl_age)
    horz2.addWidget(QLineEdit(str(self.age)))
    horz3.addWidget(lbl_attack)
    horz3.addWidget(QLineEdit(str(self.attack)))

    vertall = QVBoxLayout()
    vertall.addLayout(horz1)
    vertall.addLayout(horz2)
    vertall.addLayout(horz3)

    Overall.addLayout(verticlepic)
    Overall.addLayout(vertall)

    under_button = QVBoxLayout()
    rtrn_button = QPushButton("Return")
    under_button.addWidget(rtrn_button)

    under_button.addLayout(Overall)

    self.statuslayout = QWidget()
    self.statuslayout.setLayout(under_button)

    self.setGeometry(700, 300, 500, 75)

    rtrn_button.clicked.connect(self.mainlayout)



def Feed(self):
    horizontal = QHBoxLayout()

    self.pic = QLabel()
    pixmap = self.pixmap.scaledToWidth(250)
    self.pic.setPixmap(pixmap)

    feed_btn = QPushButton("Feed")
    go_back = QPushButton("Go Back")

    horizontal.addWidget(feed_btn)
    horizontal.addWidget(self.pic)
    horizontal.addWidget(go_back)

    self.feedlayout = QWidget()
    self.feedlayout.setLayout(horizontal)


    self.setGeometry(700, 300, 500, 50)

    go_back.clicked.connect(self.mainlayout)
```

Comment: Better would be to include a complete code that demonstrates the problem, which has been pruned down as much as possible to remove complex details. (Often you can find the problem yourself this way) First guess: in the button methods you always add a new widget to stacked; you may be ending up with many hidden widgets.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, do this only once:

```
self.stacked.addWidget(self.mainwindow)
self.stacked.addWidget(self.statuslayout)
self.stacked.addWidget(self.feedlayout)
```

and then call layouts methods with those indexes:

```
self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(0) # for mainwindow
self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(1) # for statuslayout
self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(2) # for feedlayout
```

**What was the problem:**

1. you add `mainwindow` to `stacked` at position 0, and set it: `self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(0)`, which is fine
2. you open, for example `statuslayout` which is added to position 1 to `stacked` and then set it with `self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(1)`, which is also fine
3. you close `statuslayout`, `mainwindow` is again added to `stacked`, this time at position 2 but you set widget with index 0, which is also `mainwindow`, so this will work
4. at this step it doesn't matter which button you press, for example it could be `feedlayout`: it's added at position 3 to `stacked`, but you set `self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(1)` , so `statuslayout` will be set because `statuslayout` is at position 1 in `stecked`.